# Change site title format in Wordpress (Astra theme)

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I am trying to  change the font family on **site title** by inserting this code in the *Additional CSS* option

```css
.site-title,.site-title a {
    font-family: 'Lobster Two',
     sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    letter-spacing: 1.1px;
}
```

It works but I only can see expected result just in 2 pages ( Home and Gallery). Any idea about how to get the same format in the others pages (about, my account, etc) will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

On the other pages, the .site-title is in a span, not a h1
If you use google fonts, you can also select Embed, then @import, and copy the full link to the font, then you don’t need to edit the header